# Count records for "empty" rows in multiple columns and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I' have searched a lot through the site trying to find a solution to my problem and I have found similar problems but I haven't managed to find a solution that works in my case.

I have a tickets table like this (which has a lot more data than this):

**`TICKET`**:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+
| ticketid|  report_date |   impact   |    open    |
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+
|       1 |   29/01/2019 |          1 |       true |
|       2 |   29/01/2019 |          2 |       true |
|       3 |   30/01/2019 |          4 |       true |
|       4 |   27/01/2019 |          1 |       true |
|       5 |   29/01/2019 |          1 |       true |
|       6 |   30/01/2019 |          2 |       true |
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

There is another table that holds the possible values for the impact column in the table above:

**`IMPACT`**:

```
+---------+
| impact  |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       3 |
|       4 |
+---------+
```

My objective is to extract a result set from the ticket table where I group by the `impact`, `report_date` and `open` flag and count the number of tickets in each group. Therefore, for the example above, I would like to extract the following result set.

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|  report_date |   impact   |    open    | tkt_count |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|   27/01/2019 |          1 |       true |         1 |
|   27/01/2019 |          1 |      false |         0 |
|   27/01/2019 |          2 |       true |         0 |
|   27/01/2019 |          2 |      false |         0 |
|   27/01/2019 |          3 |       true |         0 |
|   27/01/2019 |          3 |      false |         0 |
|   27/01/2019 |          4 |       true |         0 |
|   27/01/2019 |          4 |      false |         0 |
|   29/01/2019 |          1 |       true |         2 |
|   29/01/2019 |          1 |      false |         0 |
|   29/01/2019 |          2 |       true |         1 |
|   29/01/2019 |          2 |      false |         0 |
|   29/01/2019 |          3 |       true |         0 |
|   29/01/2019 |          3 |      false |         0 |
|   29/01/2019 |          4 |       true |         0 |
|   29/01/2019 |          4 |      false |         0 |
|   30/01/2019 |          1 |       true |         0 |
|   30/01/2019 |          1 |      false |         0 |
|   30/01/2019 |          2 |       true |         1 |
|   30/01/2019 |          2 |      false |         0 |
|   30/01/2019 |          3 |       true |         0 |
|   30/01/2019 |          3 |      false |         0 |
|   30/01/2019 |          4 |       true |         1 |
|   30/01/2019 |          4 |      false |         0 |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

It seems simple enough, but the problem is with the "zero" rows.

For the example that I showed here, there are no tickets with impact 3 or tickets with the open flag flase for the range of dates given. And I cannot come up with a query that will show me all the counts, even if there are no rows for some values.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? What kind of Joins are you using?

Comment: So if the range of dates is 27/1/2019 to 30/1/2019.  Would you expect to see 28/01/2019 if there were no ticket.report_dates with that value?  Your question may indicate yes, but your expected results show no.

Comment: @xQbert, that is a pretty good point. I haven't thought of that and I'm also not sure if it would be necessary to show the dates that have no tickets. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this type of problem, one way to proceed is to generate a intermediate resultset that contains all records for which a value needs to be computed, and then `LEFT JOIN` it with the original data, using aggregation.

```
SELECT
    dt.report_date,
    i.impact,
    op.[open],
    COUNT(t.report_date) tkt_count
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT report_date FROM ticket) dt
    CROSS JOIN impact i
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'true' [open] UNION ALL SELECT 'false') op
    LEFT JOIN ticket t 
        ON  t.report_date = dt.report_date
        AND t.impact = i.impact
        AND t.[open] = op.[open]
GROUP BY
    dt.report_date,
    i.impact,
    op.[open]
```

This query generates the intermediate resultset as follows :

- `report_date` : all distinct dates in the original data (`report_date`)
- `impact` : contains of table `impact`
- `open` : fixed list containing `true` or `false` (could also have been built from distinct values in the original data, but value `false` was not available is your sample data)

You can choose to change the above rules, the logic should remain the same. For example if there are gaps in the `report_date`, another widely used option is to create a *calendar table*.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10f90e768adf93622db090ec80fa276e)**:

```
report_date         | impact | open  | tkt_count
:------------------ | -----: | :---- | --------:
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 | false |         0
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 | true  |         1
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 | false |         0
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 | true  |         0
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 | false |         0
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 | true  |         0
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 | false |         0
27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 | true  |         0
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 | false |         0
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 | true  |         2
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 | false |         0
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 | true  |         1
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 | false |         0
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 | true  |         0
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 | false |         0
29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 | true  |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 | false |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 | true  |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 | false |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 | true  |         1
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 | false |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 | true  |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 | false |         0
30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 | true  |         1
```

Comment: One of the best times to use cross join and a left outer well done!

Comment: Thanks @xQbert ! Appreciated.

Comment: May need to handle missing report_Date like 28/01/2019 or May not.  Asking for clarification in a comment to the question.

Comment: @xQbert : Yes, I noticed 28/01 is missing in both sample data AND expexted results, so I assumed this was on purpose (but it's sure worth a comment on OP). I mentionned that and pintpointed the calendar solution if that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I queried against a start and end calendar table by day and cross joined all available impact/open combos and finally bought in the ticket data, counting the non-null matches.

> ```
> DECLARE @Impact TABLE(Impact INT)
> INSERT @Impact VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)
>
> DECLARE @Tickets TABLE(report_date DATETIME, Impact INT, IsOpen BIT)
> INSERT @Tickets VALUES
> ('01/29/2019',1,1),('01/29/2019',2,1),('01/30/2019',3,1),('01/27/2019',4,1),('01/29/2019',5,1),('01/30/2019',6,1)
>
> DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME='01/01/2019'
> DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME='02/01/2019'
>
>
> ;WITH AllDates AS
> (
>   SELECT Date = @StartDate 
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT  Date= DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date) FROM AllDates WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1,Date) <= @EndDate
> )
> ,AllImpacts AS
> (
>     SELECT DISTINCT Impact,IsOpen = 1 FROM @Impact
>     UNION
>     SELECT DISTINCT Impact,IsOpen = 0 FROM @Impact
> ),
> AllData AS
> (
>     SELECT  D.Date,A.impact,A.IsOpen
>     FROM AllDates D
>     CROSS APPLY AllImpacts A
> )
>
> SELECT 
>     A.Date,A.Impact,A.IsOpen,
>     GroupCount = COUNT(T.Impact) 
> FROM 
>     AllData A
>     LEFT OUTER JOIN @Tickets T ON T.report_date=A.Date AND T.Impact=A.Impact AND T.IsOpen = A.IsOpen
> GROUP BY
>     A.Date,A.Impact,A.IsOpen
> ORDER BY
>     A.Date,A.Impact,A.IsOpen
> OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                | Impact | IsOpen | GroupCount
> :------------------ | -----: | -----: | ---------:
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 09/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 11/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 12/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 13/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 14/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 16/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 17/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 18/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 19/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 20/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 21/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 22/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 23/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 24/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 26/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 27/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          1
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 28/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          1
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          1
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 29/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          1
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 30/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 31/01/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      0 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |      1 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      0 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      2 |      1 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      0 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |      1 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      0 |          0
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |      4 |      1 |          0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f394787417b161043a658479448ccd59)*